# replacing a given percentage of letters with random Ascii letters considering the length of words

Tags: python, uniform-distribution

Having a column of strings with different lengths(e.g. "Apple" , "Pear" ,"cucumber" ,"watermelon" ), there are 27 letters in total.
The aim is to randomly choose 10% , 20% , ....., 100% of these 27 letters and replace them by some random Ascii letters considering the length of the words. In a way that we choose more letters from longer words like "Watermelon" (10 letters) and less letters from shorter words like "Pear"(4 letters).

P.s:My goal is to simulate typos in a list of words and then apply Levenshtein Distance to find the best match with comparing the words with typos and the correct form of words.(e.g. converting "Apple" to "apfle" and then using LD to correct it to "Apple")

Comment: You may find some difficulties with 10% and such short strings. Like if you replace a single character in 'apple' (5 characters), that changes 20% of the string. 10% would require changing a half character, which is not very viable. Generally for distorting 10% of a set built from anything, you would count how many of that anything you have (length, count), calculate the 10% of the result, and randomly pick that many (indices) of the originals for distortion (in case of Python: ```random.sample``` can do that).

Comment: _P.s:I want to use Python code_ SO is not a code writing service. Show your efforts

Comment: @tevemadar you mean we count the number of letters in whole set (all the words) and then pick 10% of them for being replaced?
If so , again we would have the same probability for letters in short strings and long strings.
what do u think?

Comment: Based on the description I do not know if you want to distort 10% of the strings (words?) or 10% of the characters in total, or 10% of the characters in all strings (words?). And while both have something to do with "10%", there is some a difference between 'lumberjack' becoming 'lumbkrjack' (exactly 10% of characters have been distorted), or the same word becoming 'qwertyuiopa' (if all the 10 characters are distorted with 10% probability, all of them will be replaced sometimes). You have to decide what do you need exactly.

Comment: @tevemadar my desired case is "10% of the characters in total" (10% of all characters of all words.e.g.considering having ["banana", "apple", "football"], I want exactly 10 % of these 19 characters to be replaced by some random characters and in the meanwhile I want to choose more characters from  longer words like "football" than shorter words like "apple").
In general the length  of the words matters for me.I would like the long words to be affected more than short words.

Comment: ```import math```
```import random```
```import string```

```words=["bamboo",...,"pineapple","lumberjack"]```
```chars=list(''.join(words))```
```length=len(chars)```
```positions=random.sample(range(length),round(length/10))```
```print(positions)```
```print(''.join(chars))```
```for x in positions: chars[x]=random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)```
```concat=''.join(chars)```
```print(concat)```

```start=0```
```typos=[]```
```for length in (len(word) for word in words):```
```..typos.append(concat[start:start+length])```
```..start=start+length```
```print(typos)```

Comment: As the question is locked, I can not post it a normal answer, but based on your description this might be what you want. (Every break is a new line, the ```..``` represents indenting those two lines. The first loop is a single line actually, just broken after the ```:```). The idea is to get a single continuous array of the letters, distort 10% of them, and split them into words again at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood correctly, but if I did, maybe you can try something like this:

```
import random
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
output = []

for element in list_of_words:
    element = list(element)
    for n in range(len(element)):
        if random.randint(0,9)==9:
            element[n] = random.choice(letters)
    output.append(str(element))
print (output)
```

This will iterate over each letter of each word from a list, and replace it with a random lowercase letter with a 10% probability. Then it will save the resulting words to a second list of words.

Comment: thanks, so we can say  you considered 10% probability  for each letter in a column to be replaced .right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the column. This will work on a list of words, i.e. something like `["banana", "apple", "football"]`. It will go over each letter and pick a random number between 0 and 9 for each one. If it lands on 9 (10%), the letter is replaced by a randomly picked letter. Is that what you meant?

Comment: this solution is just uniform in string(Word) level , since we have the same probability of each letter of each word.so we have the same probability of noise for both short and long strings.but what I want is that the probability for short strings to be less than long strings.
i.e.I want the uniform probability in list level not word level.
Hope its clear :)

Comment: In the code I wrote the probability of noise is constant for every letter, so the probability of getting any noise depends on the length of the word, i.e. for a four-letter word the probability of no noise is 90%^4 = 66%, but for an eight-letter word the probability of no noise is 90%^8 = 43%.

I'm not sure what you mean by **"uniform probability in list level"**. If you can explain better, I'm sure I can help you as well.

Comment: by "uniform probability in list level" , I meant considering the length of the strings. 
In the example you provided , ["banana", "apple", "football"] , we have 19 letters,I would like to replace 10% of these letters in a way that more characters are chosen from "football" (8 letters) than "apple"(5 letters).

Comment: If you replace 10% of those 19 letters, then obviously more of them would be chosen from longer words.